# Create a command line interface to a Java program, run from terminal

Tags: java, terminal, command-line-interface

At the moment I'm wrangling with an existing Java project, my goal is to create a command line interface for passing arguments to it, to "run" it, so to speak.

I'm using the [Apache commons cli library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/), like so:

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.HelpFormatter;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;

public class CommandLineParameters {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    Options options = new Options();

    options.addOption("a", "abc", true, "First Parameter");
    options.addOption("x", "xyz", true, "Second Parameter");
    options.addOption("h", "help", false, "Shows this Help");

    try {
      CommandLine commandLine = parser.parse(options, args);

      System.out.println(commandLine.getOptionValue("a"));
      System.out.println(commandLine.getOptionValue("x"));

      if (commandLine.hasOption("h")) {
        HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
        formatter.printHelp("CommandLineParameters", options);
      }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

In Eclipse I can run this by modifying the `Arguments` passed to the `Run Configurations...`, however, what I would *in fact* like to do is, to be able to run this programme from a terminal shell, in an analogous way to "*normal*" terminal programmes such as `grep`, or `ipconfig`.

How can this be achieved using Java?

**NOTE:**
I'm not trying to *compile/build* this programme from the command line, I'm trying to make an *interface* to the program in the command line.

Comment: Normally I'd just leave a shell open to the directory where the project builds and run it from there.

Comment: If your asking about the command line syntax itself, the commands are `java` and `javaw` and they're described on the [documentation page.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean by that, could you perhaps point me in the direction of a resource on how to do that?

Comment: Your "note" makes no sense.  You might want to give an example of "the program" and how you're trying to call it now.  I suspect a big XY problem here.

Comment: You'd need to create a shell script to do that, so the answer depends on your operating system.

Comment: I'd just have to add it to my bash file right? and then I can call it- like they have you do with eclipse- is it so?

Comment: The idea is that you call the shell script, that then starts the JVM with your program and passes on the arguments.

Comment: yeah, I think I know what you mean- it's like, in my bash profile, I need to put into the java path the location of my compiled build/built file, like the .class file or something, and then I can call it like so, is that right?

Comment: No I mean you create a separate script that simply contains the command for running your program, and then you can put that script in your path variable (e.g. using your bash profile)

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but- could you maybe please make a toy example to show me?

Comment: Please refer to the 2 answers already posted for that.

Comment: but they don';t say to do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The provided answers describe how to build a jar that can be executed using `java -jar` command. The following article explains how to take such an 'executable' jar and convert it to a 'program' file executable by `sh` (so it can be invoked with `./program` and not with `java -jar program.jar`): https://coderwall.com/p/ssuaxa/how-to-make-a-jar-file-linux-executable

The idea is that a `zip` archive (and a `jar` is basically a flavor of a `zip` archive) may have an arbitrary prologue. The prologue is everything from the beginning of a file till `zip` file signature (4 characters, first two of which are 'PK'). When java reads a `jar` archive, it skips that prologue (everything before the signature).

So from the point of view of `java`, such a jar will be a valid jar. But if that prologue is a shell script, such a jar will also be a file that you can execute using a shell interpreter.

That means that you can prepend usual jar content with a shell script that will just invoke that `java -jar` with that same jar archive as an argument. And `java` will happily execute that `jar` ignoring the prologue.

The prologue in the article looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
MYSELF=`which "$0" 2>/dev/null`
[ $? -gt 0 -a -f "$0" ] && MYSELF="./$0"
java=java
if test -n "$JAVA_HOME"; then
    java="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi
exec "$java" $java_args -jar $MYSELF "$@"
exit 1
```

It looks for `java` and starts it with the needed parameters. This is just an example, you can tune the algorithm used to find `java` command to make it suit your needs.

And the resulting file will consist of the concatenation of this launcher shell script and that jar file (containing main class and manifest) that should be run using `java -jar`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your better option is to rewrite the other main method of the existing program to accept CLI args, but if you want to do so, either way, you need to compile the program to a class or jar file

And you run it like any other Java program from the CLI, but give it arguments like `-h` here. Note: you'll need to include a classpath for Apache Commons here.

```
java - cp <classpath> fully.qualified.CommandLineParameters -h
```

Or, if you have a JAR with a Main class attribute in its manifest and also includes Apache Commons (via an uber jar), there's no need to set the class name or classpath. Still, give the arguments, though

```
java -jar jarFile.jar -h
```

> I want it to be an independent programme, accessed from the command line, such as `ls`

Open your bashrc and [put in an alias or function](https://superuser.com/questions/977893/how-to-create-an-alias-for-standard-java-execution-command). The fact of the matter is, you *must* invoke `java`, or you can use a different JVM scripting language like Groovy

```
$ cat my-ls
#!/usr/bin/env groovy 
println "Run my other program"
$ chmod +x my-ls
```

```
$ ./my-ls
Run my other program
```

Comment: that's not what I mean. I want it to be an independent programme, accessed from the command line, such as `ls`

Comment: Then java is the wrong programming language to use... Or you simply make an alias

Answer (score 0):

That sure is possible. After parsing the parameters you can read from `System.in` and write to `System.out`. Here a very simple sample to convert input to uppercase - incomplete (error handling and such), just to show how to start:

```
package sf;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        processArguments(args);
        try {
            processInput(System.in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void processArguments(String[] args) {
        // whatever
    }

    private static void processInput(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line.toUpperCase());
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

and to execute it just use type like

```
java sf.Sample -a <input.txt >out.txt
```

the directory containing the `sf` directory where the `Sample.class` is located must be in the CLASSPATH or you must use the `-cp` option to the `java` command: [How Classes are Found](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html).

Comment: that's not what I mean. I want it to be an independent programme, accessed from the command line, such as `ls`

Comment: @s.matthew.english You mean you don't want to type "java -jar"?  I'm not sure that's possible, you have to invoke the JVM interpreter.

Comment: I just want it to be a normal programme that can be called from the command line- it *must* be possible

Comment: @s.matthew.english "Normal programm"? You probably mean binary executable or a Shell-script. You can build a simple shell script with 
java -jar CommandLineParameters.jar --param1 -param2 ...
If you will check the command line parameters then has this script more as one line.
You asked for "How can this be achieved using Java?" - you have the answer

Answer (score 0):

you should create an executable jar from your java code:

1. In Eclipse Right click on your main file
2. Choice Export->excecutable jar file
3. fill out the form. Take for "Launch configuration" your running configuration from your test

Start your application from command line:

```
java -jar CommandLineParameters.jar --param1 -param2 ...
```

Comment: is there some way that I can add this jar to my path inside of my bash profile and then just call it from the terminal noramally as I can with `ls` or `grep`?

Comment: Yes. You have to define classpath. 

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html